# Remove superscripts in Excel in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, removeall, superscript

How to remove characters that are written in superscripcts in an Excel file (.xlsx) using VBA?

They appear only in of some cells and I would like to leave other parts of thise cells (not written in supersripts) unchanged.

Copying text into other programme forgets that some letters were in superscripts, so it most probably has to be done in Excel.

Comment: Do you want to **delete** the characters, or **remove the formatting** ??

Comment: Are these regular characters to which the `superscript` format has been applied?  Or are these actual superscripted characters, such as the `2` in `4²`?

Comment: @Gary'sStudent I want to **delete** the characters. Pasting it to another program removes the formatting, so the second is not a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code takes a little bit to run but I've included code to delete the superscript or "normalize" it.

The following takes superscript characters and deletes them:

```
Sub DeleteSuperScript()
    Dim c As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each c In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        For i = 1 To Len(c)
            If c.Characters(i, 1).Font.SuperScript Then
                c.Characters(i, 1).Delete
                i = i - 1
            End If
        Next i
    Next c

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

The following takes superscript characters and "normalizes" them:

```
Sub NormalizeSuperScript()
    Dim c As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each c In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        For i = 1 To Len(c)
            If c.Characters(i, 1).Font.SuperScript Then
                c.Characters(i, 1).Font.SuperScript = False
            End If
        Next i
    Next c

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for.